# About Spectral radius of $I_n+A$

Tags: matrices

I have some questions about the spectral radius of the matrix $A+I_n$

I know that $\rho(I_n+A)=\rho(A)+1$ fails, and if $A\geq0$, then the equality holds.

(1)Is that true if $\rho(I_n+A)=\rho(A)+1$, then $A\geq0$?

(2) is the necessary and sufficient conditions on A for this equality to be hold is $A\geq0$?

Comment: Consider what happens if $A$ has large imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you give one example of a matrix $A$ for which $\rho(I_n+A)\neq\rho(A)+1$?

Comment: I choose $A=-I_n$. Then $\rho(A)=1$ and $\rho(A+I_n)=0$